# How to monitor files changes from a directory

Tags: c, linux, inotify

I am working with C but I can also use any Linux shell command.

What I need is the following:

Adding a watch to a directory. Once a file within the directory is modified (written), be notified of that event, and I would need to know which process has done this change.

What I have tried to use:

- `inotifywait` + `lsof`, but it doesn't work for me because `lsof` needs to be call while the process has the file opened and I want to call it once the process has finished modifying the file (`inotifywait` tells me `x.txt` has been modified; I call `lsof` over this file and it doesn't work).
- `auditctl`, but I can't set exactly when the log is related to a modify event.

Comment: When I click on "Edit" under this question I get a bunch of spellchecker errors right away. Don't you have this too?

Comment: Have you looked at what the full inotify messages for file changes contain.  If those messages don't contain the information about the process that changed the file, you're probably not going to be successful.  And if they do, you're home and dry, apart from provoking the `inotifywait` program into giving you the information you need, or writing one that does.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler No, the inotifywait does not provide any information related to the procces identity

Comment: Then I think you're out of luck — or, at least, you have your work cut out for you.  However, I'm not an expert on Linux monitoring, so someone else may be able to give you better news.  So, you can certainly wait, but I'm not sure you'll get good news, but I can hope for you.  Have you looked at the underlying iNotify library calls to see what information they provide?

Comment: Looking at [inotify(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html) it says: _Limitations and caveats:
       The inotify API provides no information about the user or process
       that triggered the inotify event.  In particular, there is no easy
       way for a process that is monitoring events via inotify to
       distinguish events that it triggers itself from those that are
       triggered by other processes._   Have fun.

Comment: Yeah I have read that, However I think I could find something which tell me what process was the last which edit the file. Having this when notified by inotify i would check the file in order to figure out which process modified it.